# Cheap stock images website (per image pricing)

Tags: images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are sources of free/cheap stock photos? (Additional requirements, read description.)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/what-are-sources-of-free-cheap-stock-photos-additional-requirements-read-desc)

I like the stock images and illustrations on istockphoto.com but they're kind of expensive because you have to buy a $18,50 package if you want one image that would cost $3 to $5 dollars, and the odd currency of the site makes me concerned.

So is there any website where I can get per image pricing and a good price for it? Lots of designer in this website so someone might have found a good site I assume, not asking for a free stock images website I have a big list of those but a cheap and per item priced website where an image for web won't be over $5 (800px+)

Comment: This is on topic here and I will say, my experience with iStockPhoto.com is sub par as well.  One issue is that they force you to buy odd size packages that rarely match the unit cost of images.  This in turn causes issues because your purchased points expire in 12 months if unused.  So unless you are buy new images every few months you will end up losing money.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of Creative Commons licensed photos, say, from Flickr?

Comment: Making sure that you choose photos that are allowed to be used commercially of course.

Answer (score 1):

The following offer per-image pricing for around $5:

- [Big
  Stock](http://www.bigstockphoto.com/)  - buy single images or credits.
- [Veer's Marketplace](http://marketplace.veer.com/) - encourages you to use credits, but you can buy one image only.
- [Photos.com](http://www.photos.com/) - you have to purchase an 'image pack', but they offer packs for 1 photo only.
- [Graphic
  River](http://graphicriver.net/) - add $2 if you want to buy individual images without buying credit packs.